# Upload a mp4 video and convert it in webm and ogv

Tags: jquery, video, converters

I was wondering if there's any jquery code that allows you to convert the video that someone uploads (mp4) in other 2 formats: webm and ogv to make the video compatible with all browsers...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do that using jquery. But I have worked on projects to deal with video conversion, creating animations, creating videos out of images etc.

Here is what I used, and is of great use: "ffmpeg".

So, for video conversion ffmpeg is a great framework. Here is the link for reading more about ffmpeg:

https://www.ffmpeg.org/

And here is a very helpful link to serve as a compilation guide for ffmpeg:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide

Once you are done with installation of ffmpeg, you can convert video using any scripting language. In this case I will use php as my scripting language:

So, if you are done with installation of ffmpeg, the next thing you will need to know is ffmpeg path.To know the path in linux systems, open terminal and type

```
which ffmpeg
```

it will return ffmpeg executable path, something like this:

```
/home/kiran/bin/ffmpeg
```

Once you know this, you are ready to write some simple scripts.

**convert.php:**

```
    <?php
    $ffmpeg= "/home/kiran/bin/ffmpeg"; //This is the path of ffmpeg that we got  from terminal

//The following line executes shell script
    exec("$ffmpeg -i \"input.avi\" -r 25 -c:v libx264  -s \"1920x1080\" \"output.mp4\" 2>&1", $output, $convert);

    }   
    if ($convert!=0) {
        echo 'fail to convert video to mp4 format';
    }
    else {
        echo 'success to convert video to mp4 format';
    }
    ?>
```

**Explanation:**

$ffmpeg: ffmpeg execution path

-i: input

-r 25: number of frames

-c:v libx264: library used to maintain video quality. Note that itn order to use the library, one must compile it along with ffmpeg. Details are given in compilation guide.

-s 1920x1080: resolutio of output video